# How to prepare multilanguage Windows 7 iso?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, language, wim, multilingual

I prepared WIM image with all updates and three languages: english, polish and korean. When I apply WIM image with ImageX, I can choose one of those languages. But when I replace install.wim in ISO file to my version and then I boot it, there's only english language to choose (because I used ISO with english installer).

I've got three different ISOs with all languages which I need. Is it possible to create one ISO with three languages?

Comment: Yes;  It's possible;  Your using a Windows 7 Ultimate ISO?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise ISO, because I have volume license.

Comment: Install the language packs then SysPrep the installation and create a new install.wim file

Comment: Maybe my english is not good enought, but that's exactly how I do it. I explained it in my question.

Comment: I mean my WIM file has all updates and languages which I need, but Windows installer doesn't see them. It sees only one language depending of which version of installer it is. It looks like it doesn't care about install.wim file and it doesn't know which languages it has installed. Install.wim is only used to apply files to partition. Then I apply it with ImageX, it asks about language when PC boots next time. But when I use ISO installer, it uses language selected on the beggining.

Comment: Have you verified the language packs are installed.  What language the installer is in, is based on something else, other then the language packs.  The language of WinRE which you are dealing with can be different then the language of Windows you install.